# Iterative Flood Fill implementation in C

Tags: algorithm, c, graphics

I am trying to implement an iterative version of flood fill in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int m,n;
void flood_fill(int [][n],int,int,int);
void print_wall(int [][n]);
int main(void)
{
    int i,j;
    scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
    int arr[m][n];
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    int x,y;
    printf("Enter the coordinates of the point to be repainted\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
    int new_col;
    printf("Enter new color to be painted");
    scanf("%d",&new_col);
    flood_fill(arr,x,y,new_col);
    print_wall(arr);
    return 0;
}

void flood_fill(int a[][n],int x,int y,int n)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=x+1;i<m-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=y;j<n-1;j++)
        {

            if(a[i][j]==a[x][y])
            a[i][j]=n;

        }   
    }
    for(i=x;i>0;i--)
    {
        for(j=y-1;j>0;j--)
        {

            if(a[i][j]==a[x][y])
            a[i][j]=n;

        }   
    }   
    for(i=x+1;i<m-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=y;j>0;j--)
        {

            if(a[i][j]==a[x][y])
            a[i][j]=n;

        }   
    }
    for(i=x;i>0;i--)
    {
        for(j=y+1;j<n-1;j++)
        {
            if(a[i][j]==a[x][y])
            a[i][j]=n;

        }   
    }
a[x][y]=n;
}

void print_wall(int a[][n])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("%d",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Is my implementation correct? Is the stack/queue implementation better?

Comment: `main()` seems to lack one level of indentation...

Comment: Asking for a correctness of the code which is obviously incorrect (it fails to fill up any non-convex area - in fact, it only fills rectangles)?.. Besides, revisit use of parameter `n`. Voting to close.

Comment: Correctness for corner cases is on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

1. There is no need to have `m` and `n` as global variables. Create a structure to hold your data members together and pass a pointer to that structure to your functions.
2. Variable names are too short and not intuitive: `m`, `n`, `arr`, `i`, `j`, `x`, `y` etc. Use better names (ex: `numberOfRows`, `numberOfCols` etc) that explain what the variable is doing.
3. For readability reasons I would go with a recursive implementation. My second choice would be a stack based, if recursivity is not an option. And if performance would really be an important point of my implementation that I would do something similar but:

   - I would create a struct `MatrixMap` that would hold my `matrix`, `number_of_rows` and `number_of_cols`.
   - I would represent the position of an element from the `MatrixMap` using a structure `MatrixMapCoordinate` having two `size_t` values, `Row` and `Column`.
   - An element from the `MatrixMap` can be represented using a structure `MatrixMapElement`.
   - Accessing an element can be done with a function similar with:

     ```
     const MatrixMapElement* ElementAt(const MatrixMap* fromMap, const MatrixMapCoordinate* atPosition);
     ```
   - I would move in my matrix using specialized functions such as `MoveWest`, MoveNorth`, MoveEast` and `MoveSouth`. You can even send flags to control the movement behavior: `SkipAllEmptyCells`, `MoveOneCell` etc.

Lastly, what I said at point `2` and `3` I would rewrite my algorithm as close as possible to the actual pseudocode.

```
//Read "elements" as color in the algorithm.
//  I decided to use element instead of color so you can use it in any kind of problem, regardless of what does your matrix contains.
void FloodFill(MatrixMap* targetMap, const MatrixMapCoordinate* startingCoordinate, const MatrixMapElement* targetElement, const MatrixMapElement* replacementElement)
{
    //If the starting coordinate is out of range we end the fill
    if (HasElementAt(targetMap, startingCoordinate))
        return;

    //Check if the element at the startingCoordinate is of the targetElements.
    if (ElementsAreEqual(ElementAt(targetMap, startingCoordinate), targetElement))
        return;

    //If both target and replacement are equal there is nothing to do.
    if (ElementsAreEqual(targetElement, replacementElement))
        return; 

    SetElementValue(targetMap, startingCoordinate, replacementElement);

    FloodFill(targetMap, MoveWest(startingCoordinate), targetElement, replacementElement);
    FloodFill(targetMap, MoveNorth(startingCoordinate), targetElement, replacementElement);
    FloodFill(targetMap, MoveSouth(startingCoordinate), targetElement, replacementElement);
    FloodFill(targetMap, MoveEast(startingCoordinate), targetElement, replacementElement);
}
```

Note that there is no error or pointer check. I wrote the code just to give you an idea on how it should look from a readability point of view.

You can do a similar implementation for any algorithm you choose.

Because of the poor readability in your initial implementation I didn't spend time to validate your logic. Though I would be more than happy to do it, if you refactor your code using some of the suggestions I gave you.